# rails - passing :params in url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, get, parameters, hidden-field

I am stuck one more time ... and one more time I suspect it's a stupid syntax problem:

I want to pass 2 vaiables in the url with my super simple search form.

I was expecting a URL like this:
http://mydomain/categories/search?search=pdf&os=2
But I get this:
http://mydomain/categories/search?search=pdf&os[]=

I thought it should work like this:

```
<% form_tag  search_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
  <%= hidden_field :os, params[@category.id] %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>  
<% end %>
```

... but well, it didn't do it ...

Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

Thanks!

Val

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to modify the line a bit, using `hidden_field_tag`:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :os, :value => @category.id %>
```

See the [hidden_field_tag documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#M001733) for more information.

Comment: That's great! Thank you Veger!
I end up retrieving the id via params[:symbol]:
    <%= hidden_field_tag :os, params[:id] %>
Works great!

Answer (score 2):

```
  <%= hidden_field :os, params[@category.id] %>
```

Is going to access a key in the params hash with @category.id, is there such a key? Looks like not, as its returning nil.

Seems like you want something to the effect of

```
  <%= hidden_field :os, @category.id %>
```

Comment: Hi micholson! Thanks for the quick reply!
I tried that and it returns 
http://mydomain/categories/search?search=pdf&os[2]=
(with 2 being the correct category.id)
But that doesn't give me access to the value like ...
http://mydomain/categories/search?search=pdf&os=2
..., does it?

Val